# Using Existing Android.mk file to compile library for Linux

Tags: android, ubuntu

I have a source code(c,c++) directory with an `Android.mk` file in it. When compiled with NDK, it creates `xyz.so` file to be used by another Android application.

However I want to write a similar app intended to run on Ubuntu machine and want to same above source code (i.e compile lib xyz.so for Ubuntu machine).

Is there a way I can reuse `Android.mk` file to generate `xyz.so` for Ubuntu platform?

Comment: Very unlikely the same C++ code will work for Ubuntu and Android without modifications. In any case, show the Android.mk file.

Comment: Well, actually, the source code i have is quite complex and involves multiple Android.mk file (nested in directories). As you suggested, i will surely take care of any changes in source code, however my goal is to resue Android.mk files on Ubuntu, so that I do not have to rewrite Makefiles for each of the Android.mk existing in my codebase. So far no success.

Comment: Makefiles should work fine in both systems since the build tools are similar. If you don't post more specific questions/errors really I cannot help further.

Comment: Thanks, for now I am converting to our own build system's semantics due to time constraints. Later I will try to find a way to directly use Android.mk and will post question again with specific details.